# Convert a long table in a wide table and sum between specific rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I try to find a solution for the following task - actually these are two tasks. I could do this in SQL but not in python since I'm a complete newby in coding. So hopefully you guys can help me again with this.

I track my gaming sessions (to have data I care about and then to learn python with).
To track the start time, end time and pause minutes I use a timestamp app on my phone.
Then I export the times as a csv to google drive, convert then the information from this 'long table csv' to a 'wide table form', and import this in a google sheet where other things happen.

The long form I get as csv looks like this:

| game_concat | time | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Game x-0023-pc-tv | 2023-02-23 11:42:01 | Start |
| Game x-0023-pc-tv | 2023-02-23 11:49:00 | Pause start |
| Game x-0023-pc-tv | 2023-02-23 11:58:00 | Pause end |
| Game x-0023-pc-tv | 2023-02-23 12:20:05 | Pause start |
| Game x-0023-pc-tv | 2023-02-23 12:25:05 | Pause end |
| Game x-0023-pc-tv | 2023-02-23 12:41:30 | End |
| Game xyz-0005-pc-mo | 2023-02-25 14:11:50 | Start |
| Game xyz-0005-pc-mo | 2023-02-25 15:31:21 | End |

So there are two tasks:

1. Bring this table in the following 'wide form' - see below
2. Sum break time between 'Pause start' and 'Pause end' per session (between each 'Start' and 'End')

In the end the df should look line this:

| game_id | system | screen | start_ts | end_ts | break_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0023 | pc | tv | 2023-02-23 11:42:01 | 2023-02-23 12:41:30 | 14 |
| 0005 | pc | mo | 2023-02-25 14:11:50 | 2023-02-25 15:31:21 | 0 |

I'm glad about each hint! Thank you in advance!

PS:
If it is easier to deal with, then I could also arange the original data to:

- game_concat --> 0023-pc-tv-Game x
- status --> Start=1, Pause start=2, Pause end=3, End=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

df1

```
df1 = (df
 .groupby('game_concat')['time'].agg([('start_ts', 'first'), ('end_ts', 'last')])
 .reset_index())
```

`df1`

```
    game_concat         start_ts            end_ts
0   Game x-0023-pc-tv   2023-02-23 11:42:01 2023-02-23 12:41:30
1   Game xyz-0005-pc-mo 2023-02-25 14:11:50 2023-02-25 15:31:21
```

---

df2

```
df2 = df1['game_concat'].str.split('-', expand=True).drop(0, axis=1).set_axis(['game_id', 'system', 'screen'], axis=1)
```

`df2`

```
    game_id system  screen
0   0023    pc      tv
1   0005    pc      mo
```

---

df3

```
df3 = (df['time'].diff(1).div(pd.Timedelta('1min')).where(df['status'].eq('Pause end'))
.groupby(df['game_concat']).sum()
.reset_index()[['time']].rename(columns={'time':'break_min'}))
```

`df3`

```
    break_min
0   14.0
1   0.0
```

---

concat

```
pd.concat([df2, df1.drop('game_concat', axis=1), df3], axis=1)
```

output:

```
    game_id system  screen  start_ts            end_ts             break_min
0   0023    pc      tv      2023-02-23 11:42:01 2023-02-23 12:41:30 14.0
1   0005    pc      mo      2023-02-25 14:11:50 2023-02-25 15:31:21 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out later but seems to make sense :)

Comment: Hey hey, thanks for your approach! Unfortunately I missed a point: This entire final df should be grouped by session, not by game_id. A new session starts every time the 'status' column contains 'Start'. For each 'Start' a new row should appear in the final df. I hope, one can understand my description

Comment: I got it - just added a loop in between to create a list for a new column. This enumerates all rows starting by s_id = int(input()) and adding +1 when 'status' == 'Start' ---: 
result = []
s_id = int(input())
for value in df_csvs['status']:
  if value == 'Start':
    s_id+=1
    result.append(s_id)
  else:
    result.append(s_id)

df_csvs.insert(0, 's_id', result)

Comment: I'm glad it's been solved. In fact, I don't know exactly what you mean when you talk long comment in English. So it's hard for me to help by looking at comments. I solve problem only by looking at table and code in post.